# iPhone : User option to keep the app awake

Tags: iphone, xcode, sleep

I have a count down timer that "beeps" every second it counts through AVAudioPlayer.
i want to set a user option to keep the app awake through an on/off switch.
i know that in order to keep the app awake you need to set 
`[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;` 
however how would i control the YES or NO option through a switch? Also, i noticed that after keeping the app awake for more than 5 minutes the audio (a beep sound in my case) is muted? Why is that and how can i avoid it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a UISwitch. Just connect it to the following method to your .m:

```
- (void) switchChanged:(id)sender {
    UISwitch* switch = sender;
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = switch.on;
}
```

Of course, you need to set the correct value initially:

```
mySwitch.on = [UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled;
```

And just for completion, you have to add the following lines to your .h and connect them in you .nib file:

```
@interface YourClass{
    ...
    IBOutlet UISwitch* mySwitch;
}

- (void) switchChanged:(id)sender;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am a total noob and i could use a little help. Where exactly does the void code goes? Is it going into the delegate.m ? Do i need to declare anything? Do you know how can i make the beep sound not to stop in 5 minutes?

Comment: Do you use Interface Builder for your UI? (Do you have a *.nib file?)

Comment: I have updated my answer, hope that helps! If you still have problems, you really have to work on your basic understanding of obj-c :)